# Does socket io handle ping pong automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. It has been my doubt for long time that **does socket io handles ping/pong automatically?**. I know about **pingTimeout** and **pingInterval** which led me to this confusion.
2. In order to achieve persistent socket.io connection we need ping/pong messages, **am i correct**?
3. If socket.io doesn't handle it automatically, **is it ok for creating a ping and pong events my self, client sends a ping message and server responds with a pong message in intervals**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket.io does that automatically for you. In socket.io circles the concept is referred to as a *heartbeat* mechanism instead of *ping/pong*.

The ping/pong intervals can be configured as well:

```
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  pingInterval: 10000, // how often to ping/pong.
  pingTimeout: 30000 // time after which the connection is considered timed-out.
})
```

From [the docs:](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/index.html#pingTimeout)

> pingTimeout
> Default value: 5000

> This value is used in the heartbeat mechanism, which periodically checks if the connection is still alive between the server and the client.

> The server sends a ping, and if the client does not answer with a pong within pingTimeout ms, the server considers that the connection is closed.

> Similarly, if the client does not receive a ping from the server within pingInterval + pingTimeout ms, the client also considers that the connection is closed.

> In both cases, the disconnection reason will be: `ping timeout`

You should think of socket.io as an [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) over WebSockets. It's supposed to automatically handle the trivialities of WebSocket connections so you can focus on just sending/receiving messages.

Now to answer your questions:

> If socket.io doesn't handle it automatically, is it ok for creating a ping and pong events my self, client sends a ping message and server responds with a pong message in intervals.

Yes, you can, but it's utterly unnecessary since socket.io does that for you.

> In order to achieve persistent socket.io connection we need ping/pong messages, am i correct?

No, again, socket.io does that for you.

> If socket.io doesn't handle it automatically, is it ok for creating a ping and pong events my self, client sends a ping message and server responds with a pong message in intervals.

Again unnecessary.